# why "Visual wizard" doesn't see (find) my instances?

Tags: instance

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program
    {
        public List<test> testL_I_A;
```

// doesn't see "testL_I_A" instance name
te     = new List();

```
        public enum TypeE{
       pistol, shotgun, sword 
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
    
public class test {
        TypeE tpEI;
        public Action activateA;
    }
    }
```

it also doesn't see instance's name of classes "program" or "test" if i'm creating them

Comment: i thought it is cause of "nested classes" but its not

Comment: And Visual community doesn see (show Find) my existing instances